# SLERP & skeletal animation interpolation help!

Tags: c++, animation, matrix, quaternions

I had skeletal animation in my program working fine, but I was interpolating between the *4x4* matrices stored for each bone between frames in a linear way, i.e.

```
bMatrix bMathbMathInterpolate(bMatrix const * const p_a,bMatrix const * const p_b, float p_delta)
{
    bMatrix l_mat;

   for(unsigned char i = 0;i lessthan (edit: sorry less than symbol break it) 16;i++)
         l_mat.m_values[i] = bMathInterpolate(p_a->m_values[i], p_b->m_values[i], p_delta);

   return l_mat;
}
```

Which is O.K. unless of course there is a large amount of rotation in the matrix - the model becomes slightly squashed between keyframes.

So, I made a separate interpolation algorithm than converts the *rotation part only* of a *4x4* matrix into a quaternion, performs SLERP, and replaces the *rotation part only* of the matrix with the matrix version of the quaternion. For the translation part of the matrix, I just interpolated it in a linear way.

Looking at the results, this is obviously wrong!!! :'(

If you understand all this very well (unlike myself), you're probably thinking "No! That's not how you do it!" - if so, please tell me what I'm doing wrong!!

I don't know what to do with the translation part of the matrix, because I can only find resources that tell you how to convert back and forth between a quaternion and *3x3* matrix.

Any help will be much appreciated!!!!

Comment: Quaternion conversion will help with gimble lock, but shouldn't make much difference in your calculations, I wouldn't think.  I could be wrong though as I know we use quaternion conversion within our code.

Comment: Can you post your code that uses quaternions, including your slerp function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to convert the translation component of the matrices to vectors, and then linearly interpolate them, and then convert the rotation component to a quaternion, and slerp (or lerp, or nlerp) them, and then recombine the resulting vector and quaterion back into a matrix.

Comment: It seems to me it is exactly what he does. However, it would be nice so some code as you requested.

Comment: Thanks! I had this confirmed elsewhere as well. I must have an error somewhere else. At least I know where to look now!! :):) (I thought my logic was wrong, if it's just an error in the code I can search for it) You guys are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

**Rotation matrices are orthogonal matrices with determinant of 1.**

Naive interpolation, of values between 2 transformation matrices, will not guarantee that the rotation values of the resulting matrix will orthogonal.
That means, the intermediate transformation will not be rigid information. Some kind of scaling will be applied.

*Plus:* Example code does not contain a base case that terminates the recursion.